# Convert array of x and y of a line to parabola

Tags: jquery

I have an array of x, y points of line I want to convert the array to the parabola x, y array.

http://prntscr.com/jnjplq I have this and want to convert like 
 https://prnt.sc/jnjplq this

is there any way to convert it. please suggest me the exact solution.

```
var m = Math.ceil((row.Seats.length + 1) / 2);
var b = m - 1;
var c = val / b;
var a = row.Seats[row.Seats.length - 1].x() - row.Seats[0].x();
var halfRowArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= m ; i++) {
var y = row.Seats[i].y();
if (i < m) {
        row.Seats[i].setY(y + (i + 2) * val);
        var seatText = selectedObject.findOne("#txt" + 
        row.Seats[i].getId());
        seatText.setY(y + (i + 1) * val);
        halfRowArray.push(y + (i + 1) * val);
      }
    }

    var counter = halfRowArray.length - 1;
    for (var i = m; i < row.Seats.length; i++) {
      row.Seats[i].setY(halfRowArray[counter]);
      var seatText = selectedObject.findOne("#txt" + row.Seats[i].getId());
      seatText.setY(halfRowArray[counter]);
      counter--;
    }
```

Comment: I can't see a parabola in your download - only a keyboard-type of thing?

Comment: actually, I need to make that shape as parabola